# Android: how to use cookies with API level 8 and https?

Tags: android, cookies, https

I am contacting an HTTPS server.  With API of at least level 9 I could use CookieManager / CookieHandler / HttpsURLConnection, but at API level 8 the cookie packages don't exist.

One idea I had was to just was find Android's source for API level 9 (since it's open source) and back-port just the things I need.  Is this sensible?  If so, where could I find Android's implementation of the java.net.cookie* libraries?  (Probably https://github.com/android/ as a starting place, but I could use some more guidance.)

Or is there a better way to do it with API level 8?  Can org.apache's HttpConnection handle HTTPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Apache HTTP Client](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) included to Android SDK. It has cookies support.